# Build NSS 3.35 to get Certutil in Windows 10. Error, C Compiler cannot create executables

Tags: firefox, certificate, nss, certutil

I would like to Install a certificate programmatically on Firefox version 59. I read that i need CertUtil, but the certutil code that i got on github is built from old NSS. so it only generates cert8.db and not Cert9.db, which Firefox 59 needs i assume.

So if i am correct, i need to build NSS 3.35 or higher to have a Certutil right? i went to this site to set the Windows Prerequisite and downloaded the mozilla build. and was able to build it. but it was very long so i cancelled it. I have also installed Visual Studio 2017 community Edition with the C++ compilers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Building

So i have a working mozilla-build folder and working bash prompt . And i have cloned the nspr and nss into my local folder.

So when i execute the command to build the nss, i get this error. that C compiler not working. And when i check the console.log, this is what i got.

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

```
  $ ../configure --enable-win32-target=WIN95 --with-dist-prefix=$(topsrcdir)/../dist/WIN954.0_DBG.OBJ --with-dist-includedir=$(topsrcdir)/../dist/WIN954.0_DBG.OBJ/include

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = DESKTOP-I6DF9LK
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.19(0.48/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.2
uname -v = 2016-07-13 17:45

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /local/bin
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/bin
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/kdiff3
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/node-v8.11.1-win-x64
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/nsis-3.01
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/python
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/python/Scripts
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/python3
PATH: /c/mozilla-build/python3/Scripts
PATH: .
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /mingw/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32
PATH: /c/WINDOWS
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Users/ROMMELDVO/.cargo/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2383: checking build system type
configure:2397: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2417: checking host system type
configure:2430: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2450: checking target system type
configure:2463: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2543: checking for cl
configure:2570: result: cl
configure:3054: checking for whoami
configure:3072: found /c/WINDOWS/System32/whoami
configure:3085: result: /c/WINDOWS/System32/whoami
configure:3481: checking for C compiler version
configure:3490: cl --version >&5
../configure: line 3492: cl: command not found
configure:3501: $? = 127
configure:3490: cl -v >&5
../configure: line 3492: cl: command not found
configure:3501: $? = 127
configure:3490: cl -V >&5
../configure: line 3492: cl: command not found
configure:3501: $? = 127
configure:3490: cl -qversion >&5
../configure: line 3492: cl: command not found
configure:3501: $? = 127
configure:3521: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3543: cl    conftest.c  >&5
../configure: line 3545: cl: command not found
configure:3547: $? = 127
configure:3585: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define DEBUG 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
```

I do not understand why its not able to run the cl compiler. Cause when i ran the developer command prompt for VS 2017, i can execute cl.

I don't know what is causing this error. Is it because bash cannot identify the c Compiler cl? do i have to set additional environment variables?

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem. Or if someone has a compiled NSS 3.35 with Certutil.exe, that would greatly help.

Thank you very much, Rommel

Comment: This should be a open bug [1434943](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1434943).